# When i click the play button, it shows an error saying ' Cannot read property 'play' of null '

Tags: html, reactjs

When i click the play button, it shows an error saying:

> 'Cannot read property 'play' of null '

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {

      const player = document.getElementById('player')
      const [musicIndex, setMusicIndex] = useState(0);
      const musicArray = [
        {
          title: 'koe no katachi',
          link: 'aiko- 恋をしたのはmusic video.mp3'
        },
        {
          title: 'stay alive',
          link: 'ReZero ED Ending 2 FullEmilia (Rie Takahashi) - Stay AliveENG Sub.mp3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tenshi ni fureta',
          link: '[K-ON AMV] 天使にふれたよ.mp3'
        }
      ]
      
      return (
        <div className="spotify-clone">

          <audio id='player' className='player' src={`Songs/${musicArray[musicIndex].link}`} controls></audio>
          <h3>{musicArray[musicIndex].link}</h3>

          <div className='button'>
          <button onClick={() => setMusicIndex(musicIndex + 1)}>Next</button>
          <button onClick={() => setMusicIndex(musicIndex - 1)}>Prev</button>
          <button onClick={() => player.play()}>Play</button>
          <button onClick={() => player.pause()}>Pause</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      );
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('music-player'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ref

```
import React, {useState,useRef} from 'react';
    export const App = () => {
      const playerRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
      const [musicIndex, setMusicIndex] = useState(0);
      const musicArray = [
        {
          title: 'koe no katachi',
          link: 'aiko- 恋をしたのはmusic video.mp3'
        },
        {
          title: 'stay alive',
          link: 'ReZero ED Ending 2 FullEmilia (Rie Takahashi) - Stay AliveENG Sub.mp3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tenshi ni fureta',
          link: '[K-ON AMV] 天使にふれたよ.mp3'
        }
      ]
      
      return (
        <div className="spotify-clone">
    
          <audio id='player' ref={playerRef} 
          className='player'
           src={`Songs/${musicArray[musicIndex].link}`} controls>
    
           </audio>
          <h3>{musicArray[musicIndex].link}</h3>
    
          <div className='button'>
          <button onClick={() => setMusicIndex(musicIndex + 1)}>Next</button>
          <button onClick={() => setMusicIndex(musicIndex - 1)}>Prev</button>
          <button onClick={() => playerRef?.current?.play()}>Play</button>
          <button onClick={() => playerRef?.current?.pause()}>Pause</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: wow I never actually know that useRef actually exist. thanks

Comment: If this helps, please Mark this as accepted Ans, it will help others.

Answer (score -1):

You could try maybe initializing the player inline:

```
<button onClick={() => document.getElementById('player').play()}>Play</button>
```

I don't know exactly if this helps

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use `document.getElementById` here, as at this point of time the DOM is not yet created. So instead of doing this, you should declare a new variable with useState: `const [player, setPlayerValue] = useState('');`

and then in useEffect method set the value of player variable with `document.getElementById('player')`.